# Weird behavior in request.FILES and File and handler in Django

Tags: python, django, http, django-views, django-file-upload

I have a request that is uploading two files at once. The FILES attribute of the `request` object looks like this:

```
<MultiValueDict: {u'output': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: output.txt (text/plain)>], u'history': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: .history.json (application/octet-stream)>]}>
```

I store both files as variables:

```
output = request.FILES['output']
history = request.FILES['history']
```

I then assign two file fields on a Django model to these files to try and save them but only the file field that is assigned to `output` is saved properly, the other field that is supposed to contain the contents of history contains no content.

After trying to solve this issue in the debugger I found that I am able to read the contents of `history` only once, after which `history.read()` returns an empty string: `''`.  `output` can be read as many times as I would like and it still returns the `outputs`'s actual content.

I have tried a bunch of different hacky strategies to save the content of `history`, including creating new files using `File` and `ContentFile` however it appears that django is defying any of my attempts to create a file that returns this content on `.read()`

For the record, `history` contains alot of binary-looking data that is in valid JSON format and is about 12k in size.  `file` says that it is:

```
ASCII text, with very long lines, with no line terminators
```

Is there something I am missing with the way Django is handling `history`?

EDIT: Here are the fields on the model I am trying to save (though I believe the issue is occurring before saving):

```
   history_file = models.FileField(
        upload_to=history_file_name,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
    output_file = models.FileField(
        upload_to=output_file_name,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
```

Here is the code were the model is being saved:

```
    result.output_file = output
    challenge.history_file = history
    challenge.save()
```

This issue is occuring in the post method of a CBV that is based on View.
I have not changed any of the default file handling settings that come with Django 1.6.5

Comment: Can you include the code where you save the file contents into your model?

Comment: Can you add the code in where you're setting the values and saving the model?

Comment: Also done! sorry for not adding it before

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure why this is going on but I was able to hack around this issue by doing the following:

```
history = files['history']
history_content = history.read()
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
history_content_file = ContentFile(history_content)
challenge.history_file.save(NAME, history_content_file)
```

For the record, `history_content_file` can only be read from once.

Hope this can help someone else out, I'll post more if I ever understand what went on here.